# Passing an action to a component created programatically

Tags: ember.js

Is it possible to do this?. Examples in Ember docs passes actions as part of the handlebars template.

e.g: `{{my-component action='someAction'}}`

Here's what I'm doing:

```
var containerView = Ember.ContainerView.create();

containerView.pushObject(Ember.Component.create({
  container: this.container,
  layoutName: 'my-component'
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to set the controller on the parent of the components in order to handle the actions.

`var containerView = Ember.ContainerView.create({ controller: this });`

With `this` being the controller where the component is appended to.